# Algorithm to find what points are the nearest to other points

Tags: algorithms, nearest-neighbour

I have two lists:

- Location list, it contains point of interest
- People list, it contains coordinates of every person. One single person could be in the list multiple times, depending from the log time. Someone who is out for a walk will result in two different locations in two different hours.

I would find out what people where near every point of interest.

I could approach the problem with brute force: external loop check for every point of interest the entire people list finding out who was there.

I would obviously avoid brute force. I thought about Nearest Neighbour, for sure multiple people will be in the same spot so I could look for a point of interest in the cluster.

Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Use a data structure designed for [nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).